backstage.io add programatically
I'm trying to add backstage to an organisation - I was building something similar myself - so I have a bunch of metadata on hundreds of projects already in my own database.
I want to bulk add them to backstage - had a look at the catalog/entities API endpoint, and I can read the list of endpoints - but I can't figure out how to write one
Is the any way to programmatically create a component?

turns out it was really easy - you define all your entities in a yaml file - either one or multiple - and just add it as "location" - by posting to the /locations endpoint as documented here:
https://backstage.io/docs/features/software-catalog/software-catalog-api/
What's interesting is - if that location is in github - from then on backstage will notice changes.
It was not obvious to me at all that to create a component you had to call the locations endpoint - but now I get that "locations" are basically "files that backstage knows about" - and it wants stuff to live in files, because it's designed to let you click edit and maintain something.

I would rather go to https://backstage.io/docs/features/software-catalog/external-integrations#custom-entity-providers
EntityProvider is the main class to ingest data.
Processor is just an extra optional step to add extra data, or emit extra entities.

Yes, you are looking for custom processor:
https://backstage.io/docs/features/software-catalog/external-integrations/#custom-processors
It is possible to process data from APIs or DBs.
